# Is every deterministic function borel measurable?

Tags: functions, set-theory

A deterministic function is a function that gives the same output for the same input.

$f: R^k \to R$ is a Borel measurable function then for every interval Δ, $f^-1[Δ]$ is a Borel subset of  $R^k$.

My question is: is every deterministic function Borel measurable?

Comment: No, for instance take a non-Borel set $H$ and the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in H\\ 0&\text{if }x\notin H\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being deterministic in the sense you define is an integral part of the definition of a function. Thus, you are asking whether **every** function $f : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable, and the answer to that is a clear **no**.

The easiest counterexamples are the characteristic functions of non-Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$, but non-Borel subsets tend to be a bit cumbersome to define. My go-to example would be to take the Cantor middle third set in $\mathbb{R}$, and read it as a set of infinite binary sequences, i.e. Cantor space $2^\omega$. Take a bijection $\iota : \mathbb{N}^* \to \mathbb{N}$. We say that some $q \in \mathbb{N}^\omega$ is a path through $p \in 2^\omega$, if $p(\iota(q_{\leq n})) = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, the set of real numbers $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which fall into the Cantor middle third set, and for which there exists some $q \in \mathbb{N}^\omega$ which is a path through the associated binary sequence, that set is not Borel measurable.